# SAML 2.0 Token Creation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, meteor, saml-2.0

My Node.js (MeteorJS) site will be interacting with a 3rd party platform via SSO using SAML 2.0 (their requirement). Essentially, when a logged-in user (on my site) clicks a specific link on our site, we're supposed to create a SAML token (with some specific attributes related to the user, in addition to required SAML 2.0 ones) and then POST it to the 3rd party platform's URL. They will process the token and then send a redirect to the user's browser, which will redirect the user to the 3rd party platform's site with the user being logged into the 3rd party platform's user account without the user having to log into that system, specifically. (Sorry for the re-stating of SSO basics, but I just want to be thorough to explain our the situation at hand).

The 3rd party platform is acting as the Service Provider (SP), and they have provided me with the payload attributes I need to add to the SAML Assertion (unencrypted is fine) to properly log the user into their system.

I have asked the support team at the 3rd party platform some questions about what I need to do on my side to set up the SAML engine. I have never used or implemented SAML before, so I'm learning on the fly and researching everything I can find heavily. Anyway, the support member said the following:

> Your SAML engine (acting as the IDP) creates your SAML token and that
>   token is just posted to the [3rd party platform's] endpoint. From
>   that point you’ve given all control to [the 3rd party platform] and we process the token with intent to return the redirect back into your browser window.

Since we're acting as our own IDP (we know who the logged-in user is, and we know the information that we need to send over in the SAML token based on their user account), it appears that all I need to do is create a SAML token with the appropriate attributes and just HTTP post it programmatically. Am I missing anything?

With SAML being an "older" technology and Node being a "newer" one, the documentation on implementing a SAML engine in Node is quite sparse. Most everything I see regarding SAML and Node (here on S/O and elsewhere) usually points to passport-saml, and the like, with some vague examples related to token authentication and IDP endpoints. From what I'm gathering, it seems like most all of that is overkill for what I need to do, but being a complete SAML newbie, I'm not totally sure and I'm looking to you all for your guidance.

**The abridged version of my question is:**
If I just need to POST a SAML token in a Node environment, is it as simple as creating a token with the payload attributes and setting that token programmatically in a FORM where the action is the URL provided by the 3rd party SP and the response is the SAML Assertion token? Also, what recommendations do you have for Node libraries (or at least examples with details) that would create that token for me? Most all examples and libraries I see appear to be overkill for what I actually need to provide, but having no reference to compare against, I'm not sure.

Many, many thanks to anyone who can help me out with this one!

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml as the package to create the SAML tokens. I take the SAML token it provides, I base-64 encode it, then post that token to the URL endpoint. It all seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Hey Matthew, I'm in the same situation as you.  I checked out npmjs.com/package/saml and it says it supports SAML 1.1 ... (how) were you able to get it working with SAML 2.0?

Comment: Hey @Josh, that note about it supporting SAML 1.1 is a bit misleading in my opinion. I first read it and thought it meant it only supported 1.1 and not 2.0. However, after looking around some of the files I noticed that to use SAML 2.0 you have to do something like this: `var saml2 = Meteor.npmRequire('saml').Saml20;` That did the trick!

Comment: Thanks Matthew, that helps a lot!